# Change Datagridview ColumnType from textbox to combobox

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, combobox

I have a GridView with a data source (automatically generated from Visual Studio's designer).
The datasource automatically creates the Columns in the GridView, this part is all working fine.

The problem is that i want to change the type of that column from `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, i do that like this:

[image: Screenshot]

After changing this, i get an error loading the grid:

System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

The type of the column is SQL is varchar(50).

The only code i'm using is to bind the DataSet to the GridView:

```
this.tasksTableAdapter.Fill(this.tasksDataSet.Tasks, user.ID);
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trying i found the answer.
I had to select the same DataSource for the ComboBox as i used for the DataGrid.
doing this and setting DisplayMember and DataMember, the grid loaded without errors ! :)